# How to count how many records got inserted within 5 minutes from now in a single query?

Tags: mysql

This is mostly a theoretical question, and it's mostly about MySQL.
Can I write a single query that will give me a number of records inserted from the time the query started to run until it ended, assuming the table has not timestamps etc, so this info cannot be inferred from the data in the table.

I tired this (and maybe it'll clarify the above):

```
select -(count(*) - (sleep(300) + count(*)) from my_table;
```

But it doesn't seem to do the job.
I know I can write a stored procedure to do it, but I'm just curious if there's a way to do it in a single query, without writing a new function/stored procedure.

Comment: Let's start with the problem at hand first **why** would you want to do this in a single query? Why not get the count from your application, wait 5 minutes and then get the count again? Other than that: you might want to use triggers or some other mechanism to keep ("more accurate") track of the count of records that get inserted but then deleted within the timespan (which getting the count twice will "miss")

Comment: I mentioned above, that this is mostly a theoretical question, and comes out of curiosity. It's not a question of what is the most practical way to do it, but rather, can it be done in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you really cannot, at least in theory.  Databases support the [ACID properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) of transactions.  The "I" in ACID stands for isolation, which specifically means that two queries do not interfere with each other.  In other words, a query should not see inserts that happen after the query begins.

In practice, depending on settings, `SELECT` does not necessarily behave as its own transaction.  However, it only sees the database as it is at any given instant, rather than knowing when particular changes occur.

There are proper ways to accomplish what you want.  One simple method is to completely lock the table for the `SELECT` (in MySQL you can can do that with the `for update` directive).  The query still will not be able to count the number of new rows.  But, it will know the answer anyway:  0.